# Angular change URL before finalizing page loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, iis, routes

I'm trying something in Angular and is making me scratch my head but I've seen multiple posting where this has been done.

What I want is to keep the URL in the browser static: `http://domain.com/`

in my App, when the page initializes in proceed to do

`$location.path('/home').replace();`

this changes my URL to `http://domain.com/#/home`

the page is being hosted in IIS so I tried first rewrite rules but those where not working although the rule was valid and was trapped.

on the home page I added a button that triggers the following function:

`function changeURL() { 
       if (typeof (history.replaceState) != "undefined") {
            history.replaceState(null, null, "/");
            console.log("URL changed");
        } else {
            console.log("URL cannot be changed");
        }
}`

This works to perfection! my URL is now changed. but in my javascript:

`$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoading', function () { changeURL(); });`

page loads, the URL is briefly changed to `http://domain.com/#/home` (i can see it flash in the address bar) then to `http://domain.com/#`

I believe since the browser first needs to execute and load `$location.path` the `changeURL()` will run right after the `$location.path` finishes. even though I trying to change while the `$viewContentLoading` is still in progress.

I tried to see if it was possible to change the while, during or before the `$location.path` finishes.

I tried inserting my `changeURL()` in the following events with being successful:

`$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart')`

`$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess')`

`$browser.onUrlChange()`

i also tried using instead of `$location.path()` the following :

`$state.transitionTo('^', { reload: false, inherit: false, notify: false })`

`$state.go('^', null, { reload: false, inherit: false, notify: false })`

also read is possible to `preventDefault()` on `$locationChangeStart` and do some manipulation but not really sure how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just wondering why you would like to hide the address..?

Comment: thanks @eesdil. I wasn't sure if that was best practice or not. I found this code `window.scrollTo(0, 1);` to hide the bar, is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to have static web address, but do you have many routes or just the home? And as your last comment, you want to hide the addressbar?

Comment: i have many routes. adding `$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoading', function () { changeURL(); });` to my controller changes the address bar, but it "flashes" (shows briefly) then changes it. I wish (if possible) not to change it. The site behaves similar to a app, so i don't want users landing in one of routes directly because it cause the logic of the app to break. I was thinking also to check the landing page, if not / then reroute to / and return.

Comment: Didnt really play with it, but if you redirect at the first time in IIS and after using state changes with location: false, I think it would work. Didnt realize that you are not using ui router... maybe you should :) http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state (go, location)

Comment: thank! will check the link provided. the whole reason to "fix" or reroute to / is because some of the code and authentication has not been perform if users land directly on some of the route... for now im adding this like to the begining of the controller `if (!validRoot) { $location.path('/').replace(); return; }` this fix my problem but want it to be a bit more elegant

Comment: If your concern is the authentication, and run services, than I would suggest to llook at the resolve option of ui-router. It allows you to wait for a service to be completed and the route will be activated just after: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: This approach is all wrong. There are numerous ways to manage authorization of routes and lots of tutorials about it. Suggest searching for those

Comment: I agree to have static route for this is wrong, but whats wrong with using resolve?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback will take a look at ui-router resolve. I agree I'm wasn't very happy with a static approach but I'm not very verse at routes and angular loading sequence. I will research more. Thanks again.